# C++: Safe to use locals of caller in function?

Tags: c++, pointers, stack, local

I think it's best if I describe the situation using a code example:

```
int MyFuncA()
{
    MyClass someInstance;
    //<Work with and fill someInstance...>

    MyFuncB( &someInstance )
}

int MyFuncB( MyClass* instance )
{
    //Do anything you could imagine with instance, *except*:
    //* Allowing references to it or any of it's data members to escape this function
    //* Freeing anything the class will free in it's destructor, including itself

    instance->DoThis();
    instance->ModifyThat();
}
```

And here come my straightforward questions:

- Is the above concept guranteed, by C and C++ standards, to work as expected? Why (not)?
- Is this considered doing this, sparingly and with care, bad practice?

Comment: It would be far more idiomatic to pass a `Myclass&` than a `MyClass*`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the above concept guranteed, by C and C++ standards, to work as expected? Why (not)?

Yes, it will work as expected. `someInstance` is available through the scope of `MyFuncA`. The call to `MyFuncB` is within that scope.

> Is this considered doing this, sparingly and with care, bad practice?

Don't see why.

Comment: I suspect what the questioner is talking about is the greater issue of lifetime management when you are passing pointers from place to place in C++.  This code sample is too small to really address "bad practice", but I think it's worthwhile to mention the option of using a richer class than a raw pointer...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem in actually using the pointer you were passed to call functions on the object. As long as you call public methods of `MyClass`, everything remains valid C/C++.

The actual instance you create at the beginning of `MyFuncA()` will get destroyed at the end of `MyFuncA()`, and you are guaranteed that the instance will remain valid for the whole execution of `MyFuncB()` because `someInstance` is still valid in the scope of `MyFuncA()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work. It does not matter if the pointer you pass into `MyFuncB` is on the stack or on the heap (in this specific case).

In regards for the bad practice part you can probably argue both ways. In general it's bad I think because if for any reason any object which is living outside of `MyFuncA` gets hold of the object reference then it will die a horrible death later on and cause sometime very hard to track bugs. It rewally depends how extensive the usage of the object becomes in `MyFuncB`. Especially when it starts involving another 3rd class it can get messy.

Answer (score 1):

Others have answered the basic question, with "yeah, that's legal".  And in the absence of greater architecture it is hard to call it good or bad practice.  But I'll try and wax philosophical on the broader question you seem to be picking up about pointers, object lifetimes, and expectations across function calls...

In the C++ language, there's no built-in way to pass a pointer to a function and "enforce" that it won't stow that away after the call is complete.  And since C++ pointers are "[weak references"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference) by default, the objects pointed to may disappear out from under someone you pass it to.

But *explicitly* weak pointer abstractions do exist, for instance in Qt:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qweakpointer.html

These are designed to specifically encode the "paranoia" to the recipient that the object it is holding onto can disappear out from under it.  Anyone dereferencing one sort of realizes something is up, and they have to take the proper cautions under the design contract.

Additionally, abstractions like shared pointer exist which signal a different understanding to the recipient.  Passing them one of those gives them the right to keep the object alive as long as they want, giving you something like garbage collection:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsharedpointer.html

These are only some options.  But in the most general sense, if you come up with *any* interesting invariant for the lifetimes of your object...consider not passing raw pointers.  Instead pass some pointer-wrapping class that embodies and documents the rules of the "game" in your architecture.

*(One of major the reasons to use C++ instead of other languages is the wealth of tools you have to do cool things like that, without too much runtime cost!)*

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there should be any problem with that barring, as you say, something that frees the object, or otherwise trashes its state.  i think whatever unexpected things happen would not have anything to do with using the class this way. (nothing in life is guaranteed of course, but classes are intended to be passed around and operated on, whether it's a local variable or otherwise i do not believe is relevant.)

the one thing you would not be able to do is keep a reference to the class after it goes out of scope when MyFuncA() returns, but that's just the nature of the scoping rules.